# How can I get macro name from CStyleCastExpr matcher in clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, macros, clang, llvm, clang-tidy

I using clang-tidy for a while and creating some own checks. But now I stuck in this issue. I have a cstyle cast expression from which I want to get a macro name as string.

```
#define H_KEY 5;
float *a;   
a = (float *)H_KEY; // I want to print out "H_KEY" from this expression
```

So I registered a matcher like this

```
void PointersCastCheck::registerMatchers(MatchFinder *Finder) {
    Finder->addMatcher(cStyleCastExpr().bind("cStyleCastExpr"), this);
}
```

I'm able to catch every cstyle cast and get a subExpr from it like this.

```
const Expr * subExpr = cStyleCast->getSubExpr();
```

So the clang tidy now give me information that I have "int" type sub-expression which is correct but I don't know how can I get the name of it.

What I tried was dynamic cast to **DeclRefExpr**, but this not pass. Also tried dynamic cast to **BuiltinType**, then I want to get a declaration but with no luck.

So please help. I think this should not be difficult.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If someone run in this issue, I resolve it like this.

```
if (subExpr->getExprLoc().isMacroID()) {
                SourceManager &SM = *Result.SourceManager;
                LangOptions LangOpts = getLangOpts();
                StringRef subExprText = Lexer::getSourceText(CharSourceRange::getTokenRange(subExpr->getSourceRange()), SM, LangOpts);}
```

Maybe there is better approach but this one fits my needs.